# Iterm2: how to set the current zoom as the default for new windows and tabs?

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

Iterm2 has a comfortable feature that allows us to zoom in and out using the pad or mouse scroll.

Once I zoom it to a font size that fits my needs, I want to define the **current zoom size as the default for all new windows and tabs**.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I would also really like to have this behavior but the only way I have found to get something atleast close to it is manually playing around with the font size and window size in the profile settings of the default profile until it matches my desired zoom and window size. Maybe not exactly what you wanted but so far I have not found a better workaround.

`Preferences -> Profiles -> Text -> Font size` for the "zoom"

`Preferences -> Profiles -> Window -> Settings for new Windows -> Columns/Rows` for the window size

Answer (score 0):

I simply just set my zoom, then hit command + s and now each time I launch the default proflie, it persists... could not see this documented anywhere... not sure if anything else is at play here during all my testing and mucking around to try and achieve this but I can now repeatadly set this zoom, save it, terminate the app and launch + launch new windows with the default profile (only one I have right now) and it stays... let me know if this works for you so I know it isn't just me.